# VM VirtualBox Resolution Proplem

Tags: resolution, virtualization

I am running Ubuntu on Oracle VM VirtualBox and it installed fine, but once it restarted it boxed me into the top left corner of my screen, I can not change the resolution or can find anything about it on VM settings.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install guest additions but first do:

```
sudo apt-get install dkms
```

Then:

Click on file cabinet then vboxadditions and click on run software.
Reboot guest.[image: file] [image: vboxaddtions][image: Run Software]